# SQL Server LocalDB 2014 does not create a default instance at install

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

I've recently downloaded and installed SQL Server LocalDB 2014 from Microsoft from here:

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)

After installation, there is not a default instance in the
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances` directory.

But when I install 2012 version, it creates a v11.0 directory.

In 2014 case I should create an instance manually, but I want the default instance to be there automatically.

Any ideas for resolving this?

Comment: My user is Administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

If the MSSQLLocalDB folder is deleted some how from the Instances folder, it does not return when the SQL Server LocalDB 2014 is installed again.

But after installation, after first connection using the `Datasource=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` connection string, the MSSQLLocalDB folder is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

The default instance should be in : `C:\Users\UserName\Local Settings\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB` Folder.

**[File Locations for Default and Named Instances of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547.aspx).**

Comment: I dont want my server name. My Problem is there is no MSSQLLocalDB folder when I install sql localdb 2014

Comment: I think you found it